# Using sed for change some parts of code

Tags: bash, sed

In a file htm I have several parts of the code with the following structure.
It begins with **infowindow.content=** and finishes with **";**

I need to change in these lines the first part **infowind.content=** for **infowindow.setContent(** and the last part 
**";** for 
**");**

```
infowindow.content=" Poblacio : Berlin <br> Font : Metar <br> Data : 24.04.2015 - 15:24:05 <<br> T_Actual : 14 <br> T_Max : 20 <br> T_Min : 7 <br> Rain : 5 <br>";

infowindow.setContent(" Poblacio : Berlin <br> Font : Metar <br> Data : 24.04.2015 - 15:24:05  <br> T_Actual : 14 <br> T_Max : 20 <br> T_Min : 7 <br> Rain : 5 <br>");
```

I have changed the first part with the following code, but how can I modify also the last part of the code?.

```
sed -e "s/infowindow.content=/infowindow.setContent(" /home/htm/file.htm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a capture group to "capture" all of the values between the `=` and the `;`. Then use this captured value in your replace statement to perform the substitution all in one step:

```
sed -e "s/infowindow.content=\(.*\);/infowindow.setContent(\1);/" test.htm
```

Comment: thanks Hunter, so you "capture" with \(.*\) and modify with (\1)? what does it mean here number 1?

Comment: The \1 refers the capture group. You can have multiple capture groups and your refer to them in order they were defined starting with 1

Answer (score 1):

You can try with

```
sed -i '/content/ {s/content=/SetContent(/; s/;$/);/}' file
```